postgresql streaming mode using lots of memory
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 6106 dp-post+  20   0 4507512   4.1g   4.1g S   0.0  26.6  15:20.41 postgres
 6104 dp-post+  20   0 4507552   4.1g   4.0g S   0.0  26.4   6:15.89 postgres
 6105 dp-post+  20   0 4505460 450340 449672 S   0.0   2.8   0:13.15 postgres

the above pids are causing a lot of memory usage on my standby server. When I look into pg_stat_activity for them I get this:
[local]:25011 dp-postgres@postgres=# select * from pg_stat_activity where pid in (6106,6105,6104);
-[ RECORD 1 ]----+------------------------------
datid            | [NULL]
datname          | [NULL]
pid              | 6104
leader_pid       | [NULL]
usesysid         | [NULL]
usename          | [NULL]
application_name |
client_addr      | [NULL]
client_hostname  | [NULL]
client_port      | [NULL]
backend_start    | 2024-07-11 12:26:36.08121+00
xact_start       | [NULL]
query_start      | [NULL]
state_change     | [NULL]
wait_event_type  | Timeout
wait_event       | CheckpointWriteDelay
state            | [NULL]
backend_xid      | [NULL]
backend_xmin     | [NULL]
query_id         | [NULL]
query            |
backend_type     | checkpointer
-[ RECORD 2 ]----+------------------------------
datid            | [NULL]
datname          | [NULL]
pid              | 6105
leader_pid       | [NULL]
usesysid         | [NULL]
usename          | [NULL]
application_name |
client_addr      | [NULL]
client_hostname  | [NULL]
client_port      | [NULL]
backend_start    | 2024-07-11 12:26:36.080242+00
xact_start       | [NULL]
query_start      | [NULL]
state_change     | [NULL]
wait_event_type  | Activity
wait_event       | BgWriterHibernate
state            | [NULL]
backend_xid      | [NULL]
backend_xmin     | [NULL]
query_id         | [NULL]
query            |
backend_type     | background writer
-[ RECORD 3 ]----+------------------------------
datid            | [NULL]
datname          | [NULL]
pid              | 6106
leader_pid       | [NULL]
usesysid         | [NULL]
usename          | [NULL]
application_name |
client_addr      | [NULL]
client_hostname  | [NULL]
client_port      | [NULL]
backend_start    | 2024-07-11 12:26:36.084314+00
xact_start       | [NULL]
query_start      | [NULL]
state_change     | [NULL]
wait_event_type  | Activity
wait_event       | RecoveryWalStream
state            | [NULL]
backend_xid      | [NULL]
backend_xmin     | [NULL]
query_id         | [NULL]
query            |
backend_type     | startup

Most of the fields are NULL but I supect these pids are related to the streaming process, this is my standby database. My shared_buffers is 4GB which is 25% of my total RAM which is 16GB. Could anyone help on what could be the cause of this . I executed the above SQL statement as the superuser, that is postgres

If your shared_buffers is 4GB, then you would expect almost every long-lived process to be using that much memory.  The same memory is being reported over and over.

Thanks, I understand. What would be the implications of lowering down shared_buffers?
